# Помогите решить задачу. Нужно определить группы подобия треугольников быстрее O(n^2). Условие на фото

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, математика

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Triangle {
    int var_a, var_b, var_c;    
    Triangle(){};
    Triangle(int var_a, int var_b, int var_c):var_a(var_a), var_b(var_b), var_c(var_c){};
    
    bool operator<(const Triangle &other) {
        return var_a < other.var_a || var_b < other.var_b || var_c < other.var_c;
    }
    
    bool operator>(const Triangle &other) {
        return var_a > other.var_a || var_b > other.var_b || var_c > other.var_c;
    }
    
    bool operator==(const Triangle &other) {
        return var_a == other.var_a && var_b == other.var_b && var_c == other.var_c;
    }
};

int gcd(int var_a, int var_b);

void search_big(int &var_a, int &var_b);

Triangle ascending_tr(int var_a, int var_b, int var_c);

void ascending(std::vector<Triangle> &arr, int left, int right);

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    
    int len;
    std::cin >> len;
    std::vector<Triangle> arr;
    while (len--) {
        int var_a, var_b, var_c;
        std::cin >> var_a >> var_b >> var_c;
        int var_g = gcd(var_a, gcd(var_b, var_c));
        arr.emplace_back(ascending_tr(var_a / var_g, var_b / var_g, var_c / var_g));
    }
    
    len = arr.size();
    
    ascending(arr, 0, len - 1);
    
    int ans = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        if (!(arr[i] == arr[i - 1])) {
            ++ans;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << ans;
    
    return 0;
}

int gcd(int var_a, int var_b) {
    return var_b ? gcd(var_b, var_a % var_b) : var_a;
}

void search_big(int &var_a, int &var_b) {
    if (var_a > var_b) {
        std::swap(var_a, var_b);
    }
}

Triangle ascending_tr(int var_a, int var_b, int var_c) {
    search_big(var_a, var_b);
    search_big(var_a, var_c);
    search_big(var_b, var_c);
    
    return { var_a, var_b, var_c };
}

void ascending(std::vector<Triangle> &arr, int left, int right) {
    if (left >= right) {
        return;
    }
    
    Triangle pivot = arr[(left + right) >> 1];
    int var_i = left, var_j = right;
    while (var_i <= var_j) {
        while (arr[var_i] < pivot) {
            ++var_i;
        }
        
        while (arr[var_j] > pivot) {
            --var_j;
        }
        
        if (var_i <= var_j) {
            std::swap(arr[var_i], arr[var_j]);
            ++var_i, --var_j;
        }
    }
    
    ascending(arr, left, var_j);
    ascending(arr, var_i, right);
}

/*

3
6 6 10
15 25 15
35 21 21

4
3 4 5
10 11 12
6 7 8 
6 8 10

*/
```

[image: Задача упала на тесте, никак не могу придумать подходящего решения удовлетворяющего ограничениям.]

Comment: А являются ли треугольники подобными с точностью до зеркального отображения? Например, (3,4,5) и (3,5,4)?  Судя из примера 2 — нет? Да, а URL задачи с проверяющей системой нет? Проверить идеи?

Comment: К сожалению это закрытый контест и я бы конечно все предоставил. Вот я вопрос про зеркальное отображение не понял, ведь там все как раз подходит.

Comment: Да, не доглядел. Вопрос остается открытым — (3,4,5) и (3,5,4) относятся к одному классу или к разным? Смотрите, вы один такой, из бумаги вырезанный, на второй на второй не наложите, если только не перевернете. Вот и вопрос - это играет роль или нет?...

Comment: Нет, не играет. Их можно для удобства поссорить. Я там нарешал и понял, что не прав, а сейчас я могу написать решение только за квадрат.

Comment: Попробуйте такой вариант, он хоть и O(n^2), но даст какое-то понимание того, насколько они данные дают неприятные... Потом придется думать дальше. https://ideone.com/74YFg5

Comment: И еще попробуйте этот вариант... — https://pastebin.com/8W7VGH07 Если пройдет — дам в ответ :)

Comment: Квадрат там точно не зайдет из-за ограничения n <= 10^6. Я объясню свое решение может Вы мне подскажете что не так. Я нахожу gcd всех сторон треугольника, делю на каждую сторону, после я сортирую стороны и все треугольники заношу в вектор, после я сорчу этот вектор и за n нахожу такие группы путем подсчета стыков разных групп (эти группы возникают в ранее отсорченом векторе). Например (6, 6, 10) gcd = 2 => (3, 3, 5); (15, 25, 15) gcd = 5 => (3, 3, 5). Получаем коэффициент подобия двух треугольников равен 5/3 или 3/5

Comment: Решение с пастбина хорошее, я попробую его залить, но оно может не зайти из-за проверки форматирования, может поругаться на unordered_set

Comment: Мне кажется, деление использовать в этой задаче нельзя.

Comment: Я залил Ваш вариант, но проверка оформления заблочила данное решение из-за unordered_set. Я бы попробовал его переписать, но я немного не понимаю некоторых вещей относительно структуры triHash.

Comment: Зря вы не пишете в начале комментария @Harry - в результате я только сейчас увидел :) Словом, можно легко заменить `unordered_set` на `set`, время для миллиона у меня увеличилось примерно в 2 раза, но до секунды все равно не дотягивало.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `unordered_set`:

```
struct tri
{
    unsigned long long a, b, c;
    tri(unsigned long long aa,
        unsigned long long bb,
        unsigned long long cc):a(aa),b(bb),c(cc)
    {
        if (a > b) swap(a,b);
        if (b > c) swap(b,c);
        if (a > b) swap(a,b);
        unsigned long long g = gcd(a,gcd(b,c));
        a /= g;
        b /= g;
        c /= g;
    }
};
 
bool operator == (const tri& x, const tri& y)
{
    return (x.a == y.a) && (x.b == y.b) && (x.c == y.c);
}
 
struct triHash
{
    std::size_t operator()(const tri& t) const noexcept
    {
        std::size_t h1 = std::hash<unsigned long long>{}(t.a);
        std::size_t h2 = std::hash<unsigned long long>{}(t.b);
        std::size_t h3 = std::hash<unsigned long long>{}(t.c);
        return h1 ^ (h2 << 1) ^ (h3 << 3);
    }
};
 
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    unordered_set<tri,triHash> v;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int a,b,c;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        tri t(a,b,c);
        v.insert(t);
    }
    cout << v.size();
}
```

Вариант с обычным `set`:

```
struct tri
{
    unsigned long long a, b, c;
    tri(unsigned long long aa,
        unsigned long long bb,
        unsigned long long cc):a(aa),b(bb),c(cc)
    {
        if (a > b) swap(a,b);
        if (b > c) swap(b,c);
        if (a > b) swap(a,b);
        unsigned long long g = gcd(a,gcd(b,c));
        a /= g;
        b /= g;
        c /= g;
    }
};

bool operator == (const tri& x, const tri& y)
{
    return (x.a == y.a) && (x.b == y.b) && (x.c == y.c);
}

bool operator < (const tri& x, const tri& y)
{
    return tie(x.a,x.b,x.c) < tie(y.a,y.b,y.c);
}

 
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    set<tri> v;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int a,b,c;
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        tri t(a,b,c);
        v.insert(t);
    }
    cout << v.size();
}
```